pgfplots / 2D contour filled plot from a csv file
Trying to plot a 2D colormap of my data like this:

Here's my MWE with a sample of data. x,y are the coordinates. P is the value on which I want to base the shading.
\documentclass[border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{filecontents}{test.csv}
        x,y,P
        0.6029680189,0.7383407645,2.3729000000
        0.5323565117,0.6601831742,3.2726000000
        0.4677196601,0.5882540709,4.0038000000
        0.0946800948,0.6688882286,5.0510000000
        0.1884371445,0.6355349568,5.0222000000
        0.2792665104,0.5997515545,4.8900000000
        0.3623180375,0.5641482523,4.6771000000
        0.4853625211,0.1178246418,5.0150000000
        0.4696592171,0.2354673908,4.9738000000
        0.4525723312,0.3510530681,4.8490000000
        0.4353225341,0.4584688067,4.6566000000
    \end{filecontents}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            view = {0}{90},
            colorbar,
            ]
            \addplot3[
            contour filled={number = 20}
            ]
            table[x=x, y=y, z=P, col sep=comma]{test.csv};
        \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The code above was throwing: ERROR: shader=interp: got unsupported pdf shading type '0'.
*****After more searching, I modified my MWE as follows. I don't get any errors, I just get an empty plot :-(
\documentclass[border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{filecontents}{test.csv}
        x,y,P
        0.6029680189,0.7383407645,2.3729000000
        0.5323565117,0.6601831742,3.2726000000
        0.4677196601,0.5882540709,4.0038000000
        0.0946800948,0.6688882286,5.0510000000
        0.1884371445,0.6355349568,5.0222000000
        0.2792665104,0.5997515545,4.8900000000
        0.3623180375,0.5641482523,4.6771000000
        0.4853625211,0.1178246418,5.0150000000
        0.4696592171,0.2354673908,4.9738000000
        0.4525723312,0.3510530681,4.8490000000
        0.4353225341,0.4584688067,4.6566000000
    \end{filecontents}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            %view = {0}{90},
            colorbar,
            ]
            \addplot[contour filled={number = 8,labels={false}},
                mesh/rows=100,mesh/cols=100,mesh/check=false,
                patch type=bilinear,
                point meta=explicit,
            ]
            table [x=x, y=y, z=P, col sep=comma]{test.csv};
        \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

